# How to filter collection in Mongo C# driver?

Tags: mongodb, c#-4.0, group-by, filtering, mongodb-.net-driver

I know Mongodb for Linq doesn't support **group** Operation!
So, I found group with Mongo C# driver as `group by` in LINQ.
I have read mongo-csharp-driver examples, but these are not group examples with filtering.
Please, tell me, thanks.

This is my code.

```
var Table = DatabaseLinq.GetCollection<Model.Urls>(TableName).FindAll().AsQueryable();
var queryData = (from item in Table
        group item by item.Url)
        .OrderByDescending(p => p.Sum(x => x.ViewsCount))
        .Skip((PageIndex - 1) * PageSize)
        .Take(PageSize);
```

This is my group by, but how can I add filter here?

Comment: this is my group by ,but ,how add filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add filter by using `Find()` instead of `.FindAll()` method, like this:

```
var Table = DatabaseLinq.GetCollection<Model.Urls>(TableName)
  .Find(Query<Model.Urls>.EQ(x => x.Url, "Ken")).AsQueryable();
var queryData = (from item in Table
        group item by item.Url)
        .OrderByDescending(p => p.Sum(x => x.ViewsCount))
        .Skip((PageIndex - 1) * PageSize)
        .Take(PageSize);
```

Comment: what's the assembly for Query?

Comment: [This is legacy now](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_Builders_Query_EQ.htm)

Answer (score 1):

```
var Filter = new BsonDocument("ProductName", "WH-208");
var list = await collection.Find(Filter).ToListAsync();
```

*In the above line 'ProductName' is the KEY and 'WH-208' is the VALUE to search.*

[Refference](http://www.fourthbottle.com/2015/07/filtering-mongodb-data-using-csharp-and-.Net.html)